# No successful boot without quick detour into recovery mode

Tags: boot, xfce, recovery-mode

My Ubuntu 20.04 (vanilla Ubuntu but using Xfce as default desktop) seems to have fallen into a rut in which successful boot is possible if I boot into recovery mode, going as far as the usual login screen (but displayed at reduced resolution), at which point instead of logging in I choose the restart option using the upper right corner ⏻ thing, upon which an eventually successful normal-mode reboot begins. The unsuccessful boot that results if I do not go through this procedure is always an apparently stuck situation, sometimes on the black screen, sometimes on the Ubuntu screen with the four rolling dots. By stuck I mean easily 10 minutes without snapping out of it. I can't say with confidence that, had I waited longer, it would not eventually have snapped out of it. The main partition for this system is only 75% full. This behavior started last night. The last session I had before this problem appeared, I mounted a flash drive that the file manager read as blank, at which point I decided that the system was acting weird and therefore due for a reboot, the first of which got stuck on the black screen for a good 10 minutes. I went though this apparently infinite stuckness cycle (randomly either black screen or Ubuntu screen) a dozen or so times, with hard power cycles between attempts (as there was no response to ctrl-alt-f2, and I couldn't think of anything else to try). Eventually I stumbled on the "take recovery mode as far as the login screen" trick, which so far has worked all two times I've tried it so far.

Comment: So it only happens when you power up after a complete shutdown? Try pressing **e** at the grub menu and then editing your GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset" and see if that will boot.

Comment: Indeed, it does. Thanx.

Comment: Goot to know. I am not sure nomodeset is a suitable permanent solution, perhaps some experts will comment for us. If you feel it is stable like this, you can easily make it permanent so you don't have to edit the grub load each time. If you need a hand let us know.